# Go Gin Validate: Return errors as JSON

Tags: validation, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have two GORM models in my app:

```golang
type Author struct {
    Model
    Name  string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Books []Book `json:"books" gorm:"foreignkey:AuthorID" binding:"dive"`
}

type Book struct {
    Model
    Name     string    `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    AuthorID uuid.UUID `json:"-"`
}
```

Using Gin, I'm trying to validate the posted data:

```golang
func createAuthor(c *gin.Context) {
    var author Author
    if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&author); err != nil {
        errors, _ := err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
        e := make(map[string]string)
        for _, err := range errors {
            e[err.Field()] = err.Tag()
        }
        c.JSON(400, e)
        return
    }
    db.Create(&author)
    c.JSON(200, author)
}
```

When posting something like:

```js
{
    "name": "Author name",
    "books": [
        {}
    ]
}
```

You'll get a response with the errors like this:

```js
{
    "Name": "required"
}
```

What I would like to get is the following:

```js
{
    "books": [
        {
            "name": [
                "required"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you set different binding message for Author.Name and Book.Name. I suspected that the response message you received is because Book.Name is empty.